# Interactions in Survival Analysis using lognormal models -how to interpret?

Tags: survival

Do you know how to interpret the odds in Survival Analysis using lognormal models?

UCLA stata page has an excellent example on how to interpret interactions in proportional models, but how to do that with lognormal models?

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/seminars/stata-survival/

Thank you!

Below are the results. z2ro is the IV, and z2inno is the moderator. What are the odds of the main effect at different values of the moderators?

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe interactions in log-normal models would be any different?

Comment: I did some calculations but not sure if I got it right. Are you able to help take a look?